# Update Every row in MYSQL with Unique Value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to assign a field called 'uniqueid' to each row present in my database. There are roughly 188,000 rows available.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("comics",$connection) or die ("Database not found");

$query = mysql_query("select * from comic_issues"); 

if ($query){
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

  foreach($rows as $row){
    $str = strtolower($row['series'].$row['volume'].$row['issue']);
    $str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $str);

    $update = "update comic_issues set uniqueid='" . $str . "' where id='" . $row['ID'] . "'";
    mysql_query($update);

    exit();
  }
}
```

What is happening is that every row gets updated with the same uniqueid, which seems to be a different value each time I run the script.

Comment: Why not just apply the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute to `uniqueid` (if it's an integer data type) and leave MySQL to do the rest for you?

Comment: @eggyal I am using this field to be able to sync uploaded CSV files with my internal data. Their content may not match mine, hence the uniqueid field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
foreach($rows as $row){
```

you need to do

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
```

In your code `$rows` is a number and not an array, therefore you can't do a foreach on it.

Comment: Alternatively you could also generate a hash from the 3 values and use that for your unique ID. Eg. `$str = md5($row['series'].$row['volume'].$row['issue']);` Then you don't have to any about **any** special characters!

Comment: I tried this code (the while) and it still does not work. Hmmm.

Comment: You might have another problem in your code. Need some more details about the problem. You should probably try to echo $str and $update to the screen and see if they contain the correct strings... And oh, you are also stopping your script after updating the first row you find - because of your exit() - you don't want that there.

Answer (score 1):

Just let MySQL do it all for you:

```sql
UPDATE comic_issues SET uniqueid = LOWER(CONCAT(series,volume,issue))
```

If you must also strip all non-alphanumeric characters, you can either write a stored function or else use a UDF.

Comment: What about special chars? Lots of them have hyphens or apostrophes.

Comment: @TerryGodier: If you're only concerned with hyphens and apostrophes, you could apply `REPLACE()` twice.

Comment: there could be additional special chars including spaces, commas, whatever in the data.

Comment: @TerryGodier: Then I would suggest using a UDF, e.g. [lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme).